# Python functions objects type

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, object

If I do:

```
def foo():
     pass

type(foo)
```

I get:

```
<class 'function'>
```

Then when I do:

```
print(function.__dict__)
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

But if I do:

```
print(str.__dict__)
```

I get the `__dict__`  of the class `str`.

Why can I access the `__dict__`  of the class `str` but can't  access the `__dict__` of the class `function`?

Comment: Because `function` isn't a built-in name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `function` type is not available as a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs).

There are plenty of object definitions defined by the Python core engine that don't need to clutter up a namespace that is available everywhere. You won't normally be using that object directly anyway. The list of objects that are available everywhere (or via the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)) is carefully curated to only contain things that you'd regularly need when writing Python code.

You still can access the type, as you've seen with `type()`, so use that:

```
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(foo).__dict__
mappingproxy({'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'function' objects>, '__call__': <slot wrapper '__call__' of 'function' objects>, '__get__': <slot wrapper '__get__' of 'function' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x102e5f030>, '__closure__': <member '__closure__' of 'function' objects>, '__doc__': <member '__doc__' of 'function' objects>, '__globals__': <member '__globals__' of 'function' objects>, '__module__': <member '__module__' of 'function' objects>, '__code__': <attribute '__code__' of 'function' objects>, '__defaults__': <attribute '__defaults__' of 'function' objects>, '__kwdefaults__': <attribute '__kwdefaults__' of 'function' objects>, '__annotations__': <attribute '__annotations__' of 'function' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'function' objects>, '__name__': <attribute '__name__' of 'function' objects>, '__qualname__': <attribute '__qualname__' of 'function' objects>})
```

You can also access it via the `types` module, as the [`types.FunctionType` name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType):

```
>>> types.FunctionType
<class 'function'>
```